# Passing Javascript variables in php

Tags: php, javascript

I have 2 pages: details.php and terrainChooser.php

Terrain Chooser creates a td tag with an element and adds to it 3 input type="hidden" with information to retrieve.

```
window.opener.document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "
<input readonly type='text' style='background-color:#eed8bb;border:0;' name='parcName" + parcNum + "' value=\"" + txt + "\" />
<input type='hidden' id='parcId" +parcNum + "' value='" + id + "' />
<input type='hidden' id='regID" + parcNum + "' value='" + regID + "' />
<input type='hidden' id='muni" + parcNum + "' value=" + muni +" />";
```

Inside details, they have been retrieved for a purpose and are used to display the values of the 3 input type hidden.

My question is, how do i go about using those javascript variables to say pass them through an sql statement in my php part say:

```
$SQL = "update T_TOURNOI_PARC set
F_PARCID1 = $parc[0],
WHERE F_TOURNOIINFOID = $tournoiId";
$rs->execute($SQL);
```

Where $parc[0] would have the 3 values.

This doesn`t work but is there something like this i can use?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![[CDATA */
var test = document.getElementById['muni1'].value
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?php
$test = ('<script type="text/javascript">test</script>');
?>
```

Comment: This code `$test = ('<script type="text/javascript">test</script>');
` is executed before this code `var test = document.getElementById['muni1'].value`. JavaScript: Client side, PHP: server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the inputs in a form and post them to another script to handle the parameters. Take a look at http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php

Comment: looking at the source : http://pastebin.com/8ZU6gzCc

Comment: i'm not quite sure how to change it

Answer (score 1):

Javascript runs in the *browser* and is not connected to your PHP (which is on the server)

You need to send the data back to the server using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs in the browser, PHP runs on the server. PHP can insert Javascript code into the page as it's generated, but to get Javascript to send something back to PHP, you'll need to use AJAX.